Additional CSS classes not being added in Gutenberg editor
When we add additional classes to our custom block they are not being added in the editor. When we save the block and view the front-end the additional classes are showing. But in the editor they won't show up.
Here is the code of our block:
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';


export default {
    name: 'erik-dekker/button',
    title: 'Knop',
    icon: 'button',
    category: 'erik-dekker',
    edit: () => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();

        return (
            <div { ...blockProps }>hello world!</div>
        );
    },
    save: () => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

        return (
            <div { ...blockProps }>hello world!</div>
        );
    }
}

Thanks for your time!

can you declare the API version in your block? The examples use api version 3 but your code doesn't declare it in your block registration. The behaviour of the block editor and your block changes with this, e.g. some features are not available if you're using API v1
